# trigger failed -ORA-04098 is invalid and failed re-validation sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create or replace trigger "STUDENT_PERSONAL_DETAIL_T1" 
AFTER insert or update or delete on "STUDENT_PERSONAL_DETAIL" 
for each row 
begin 
  insert into fa1 (s_id,name,class,sec) 
  select reg_no,name,class,sec 
  from inserted 
end;
```

This is the trigger created using Oracle xe trigger creating interface.

It is created without error but when a insert is called on the table trigger error is shown
`trigger failed -ORA-04098 is invalid and failed re-validation`.

Guidance and suggestions will help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
REFERENCING new AS new
...
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO fa1(s_id, name, class, sec)
          VALUES (:new.reg_no, :new.name, :new.class, :new.sec);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

see, this select statement is invalid, because there is no such table as `inserted`

```
select reg_no,name,class,sec 
from inserted
```

**EDIT** if you want to log the inserted values into table fa1, you would do something like, if you had the following columns in table `STUDENT_PERSONAL_DETAIL`: `reg_no,name,class,sec`

```
create or replace trigger "STUDENT_PERSONAL_DETAIL_T1" 
AFTER insert on "STUDENT_PERSONAL_DETAIL" 
for each row 
begin 
  insert into fa1 (s_id,name,class,sec) 
  values (:new.reg_no, :new.name, :new.class, :new.sec)
end;
```

Note the clause `AFTER insert on "STUDENT_PERSONAL_DETAIL"`. I have omitted `or update or delete` to make sure this will only be triggered for newly inserted records. (because you tried to select from table 'inserted', I have concluded that's what  you want to do)

Comment: its in oracle docs that a newly inserted row is referred as inserted and the same keyword "inserted" can be used in queries.

Comment: thanks for mentioning, that is interesting. could you please link the relevant part of the oracle docs?